# why am i having an error when trying to refer to the arrray element?

Tags: .net, vb.net

how can I reference the array elements. I am trying  to use 0,1,2,3,4 at the moment but it throws back

> "IndexOutOfRangeException"

```
Dim IndividualResults As String() = results.Split(New Char() {";"})
            For Each IndividualResult In IndividualResults
                Dim words As String() = IndividualResult.Split(New Char() {","})
                strStudentFirstName = words(0)
                strStudentLastName = words(1)

                intScore1 = CInt(words(2))
                intHighestScore = intScore1

                intScore2 = CInt(words(3))
                If intScore2 > intHighestScore Then
                    intHighestScore = intScore2
                End If

                intScore3 = CInt(words(4))
                If intScore3 > intHighestScore Then
                    intHighestScore = intScore3
                End If
```

Comment: Test the bounds of the array before interacting with specific elements.

Comment: Show sample text and use the debugger, also set `Option Strict` to `On`(`","` is not a `Char` but a `String`).

Comment: I tested this piece of code - worked.

Comment: and to get the highscore:             Dim scores As New List(Of Integer)
            scores.Add(words(2))
            scores.Add(words(3))
            scores.Add(words(4))
            Dim hs = scores.Max()

Comment: thankyou, I now have this working. fo some reason changing it from a for each to for I worked. but I had to have -2 a the end.( even though theoretically it would only save two records) but it still works so whatever haha

Comment: For i = 0 To IndividualResults.Length - 2
            Dim words As String() = IndividualResults(i).Split(New Char() {","})
            strStudentFirstName = words(0)
            strStudentLastName = words(1)

            intScore1 = CInt(words(2))
            intHighestScore = intScore1

            intScore2 = CInt(words(3))
            If intScore2 > intHighestScore Then
                intHighestScore = intScore2
            End If

            intScore3 = CInt(words(4))
            If intScore3 > intHighestScore Then
                intHighestScore = intScore3
            End If

Comment: -2 works because you have less than the expected number of elements. Really, do, test the bounds of the array before interacting with the elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible safer option if you're dealing with an unknown number of elements in your array(s)

```
Private Sub testSplits()
    Dim results As String = "James,Jones,1;Julie,Bond,2,3;Eric,Haskell,4,5,6;;"
    splitValues(results)
End Sub

Private Sub splitValues(results As String)

    Dim strStudentFirstName As String
    Dim strStudentLastName As String

    Dim IndividualResults As String() = results.Split(Convert.ToChar(";"))
    For Each IndividualResult As String In IndividualResults

        Dim words As String() = IndividualResult.Split(Convert.ToChar(","))
        Dim wordCount As Integer = words.GetUpperBound(0)

        If wordCount > 0 Then

            strStudentFirstName = words(0)
            strStudentLastName = words(1)

            Dim scores As New List(Of Integer)
            If wordCount >= 2 Then
                scores.Add(CInt(words(2)))
            End If
            If wordCount >= 3 Then
                scores.Add(CInt(words(3)))
            End If
            If wordCount > 3 Then
                scores.Add(CInt(words(4)))
            End If

            Dim highestScore As Integer = scores.Max()

            Debug.Print(String.Concat("Student ", strStudentFirstName, " ", strStudentLastName, " : Highest score: ", highestScore))

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```